# MySQL how to use CONCAT in IN condition?

Tags: mysql

This SQL works ok:

```
SELECT * from table_name where id IN (473,473,475);
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT * from table_name where id IN CONCAT('(', '473,473,475', ')');
```

It says:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT('(', '473,473,475', ')')' at line 1
```

Why?

I want to use it something like this:

```
SELECT * from table_name where id IN CONCAT('(', ids, ')');
```

ids is varchar and contains something like this:

```
473,473,475
```

Comment: What's in `ids`? If it's an array, you should use application-layer concatenation, not DB one.

Comment: Why do you want to concat `(` with the numbers?

Comment: If you `concat` `(` with `ids` you get something like `(123,456,789)`. If that's the idea you can use `SELECT * from table_name where id='(123,456,789)'`. You can use a prepare statment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, ids);
```

The parameter to `IN` must be either a literal list or a subquery. `CONCAT()` returns a string, not a list -- SQL doesn't re-parse the result.